# How are these two exponential logarithmic equations equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How does following assertion hold? I have tried some real values but can anyone explain it to me mathematically/algebraically? 
$$
a^{\log_{b}n} = n^{\log_{b}a}
$$

I'm reading something that asserts this, but I do not see the connection. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

taking the logarithm on both sides we have
$$\log_b n\ln(a)=\log_b a\ln(n)$$ after this we have
$$\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(b)}\ln(a)=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}\cdot \ln(n)$$

Comment: It would have been a little easier to have taken the $\log_b$ of both sides instead of the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method:

$$\log_ac=\frac{\log_bc}{\log_ba}$$

$$\log_ac\cdot\log_ba=\log_bc\cdot\log_aa$$
$$\log_ac^{\log_ba}=\log_aa^{\log_bc}$$
$$c^{\log_ba}=a^{\log_bc}$$